# Design iterator adaptor to convert between unrelated objects

Tags: templates, iterator, c++14, template-meta-programming

I have the following MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class LegacyWidgetData
{
  private:
    double _a;
    double _b;

  public:
    LegacyWidgetData()
      : _a(0), _b(0)
    {}

    LegacyWidgetData(const double &a, const double &b) 
      : _a(a), _b(b)
    {}

    LegacyWidgetData(const LegacyWidgetData& w)
      : _a(w.a()), _b(w.b())
    {}

    inline double &a()
    {
      return _a;
    }

    inline double a() const
    {
      return _a;
    }

    inline double &b()
    {
      return _b;
    }

    inline double b() const
    {
      return _b;
    }
};

template <std::size_t D>
class GenericWidgetData
{
private:
  double data[D];

public:
  GenericWidgetData(double a, double b)
  {
    data[0] = a;
    data[1] = b;
  }

  GenericWidgetData(double a, double b, double c)
  {
    data[0] = a;
    data[1] = b;
    data[2] = c;
  }

  double get(int idx)
  {
    return data[idx];
  }

  void set(int idx, const double& v)
  {
    data[idx] = v;
  }
};

template <typename Iterator>
void dummyFunction(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
  for (auto it = begin; it != end; it++)
  {
    cout << "Before: " << it->a() << "," << it->b() << "\t";
    it->a() += 1;
    it->b() -= 1;
    cout << "After: " << it->a() << "," << it->b() << "\n";
  }
}

int main()
{
  vector<LegacyWidgetData> c1{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
  dummyFunction(c1.begin(), c1.end());

  vector<GenericWidgetData<3>> c2{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

  // dummyFunction(c2.begin(), c2.end());  // Will not compile
  return 0;
}
```

I have the following assumptions/restrictions:

1. I cannot modify the implementation of `LegacyWidgetData` or `dummyFunction`
2. I can add methods to `GenericWidgetData`, and add any iterator adaptors as may be needed.

What I'd like to have is some sort of a iterator adaptor that when applied to any kind of iterator of `GenericWidgetData` gives me an iterator that acts like an iterator of `LegacyWidgetData`, without any caching/creation of intermediate object involved. Big props if this can be done in compile-time using template meta programming!

Comment: Why would you expect it to compile as `dummyFunction` use members functions `a` and `b`which does not exists  in `GenericWidgetData`. **It might help to read compiler error message!**

Comment: @Phil1970 It might help if *you read the question in its entirety*

Comment: **Read your question again** and tell me **where** is the question. The purpose of the site is not to write code for other peoples or do their homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is add a template specialization to `GenericWidgetData` for when `D == 2` and then implement the `.a()` and `.b()` functions to match `LegacyWidgetData`'s interface.

Even if an iterator adapter that could switch at compile-time with some metaprogramming tricks could be written, it would be very complicated to be understood by anyone but its own writer.

Comment: You overlooked the restraint that I cannot edit `dummyFunction` (which is just one of a thousand different functions that accept iterators of `LegacyWidgetData`) - without that restraint, the problem becomes *much* simpler.

Comment: @TCSGrad Ah, apologies. Well, you're in quite a pickle then. You could probably add a templare specialization to `GenericWidget` for `D == 2` that includes member functions `.a()` and `.b()` to comply with `LegacyWidget`'s interface.

Comment: That actually makes sense for this toy example, but not for my actual code base (which basically wraps the iterator in a another class which has some custom properties) - seems I have to distill the problem into a better example without simplifying  it too much! 

If you can edit you answer to reflect your comment, I'll accept it and work on a better MWE for a different question.

Answer (score -1):

If you have iterator adaptor, then you would typically need two such objects.

And if you have a lot of those algorithms, then it would make sense to hide the vector inside another class whose begin/end method would returns adaptors instead.  Something more or less like that:

```
templace <std::size_t D> class MyContainer
{
public:
    MyAdaptor<D> begin();
    MyAdaptor<D> end();
private:
    std::vector<GenericWidgetData<D>> data;
};
```

However, it might make sense to simply add the appropriate functions to `GenericWidgetData`. In that case, you might want to have some specializations so that for example `b()` is only available if size is 2 or more etc.

Neverthless, the best solution would probably be to modify the 1000 functions so that instead of accessing directly members of `LegacyWidgetData`, then would call a free function.

```
double& b(LegacyWidgetData &data) { return data.b(); }
const double& b(const LegacyWidgetData &data) { return data.b(); }
```

And you would then add overloads for GenericWidgetData as appropriate. Using `static_assert`for validation might work relatively well in that case:

```
template <std::size_t D> double& b(GenericWidgetData<D> &widgetData)
{
    static_assert(D > 1, "b is available only if D is big enough");
    return widgetData.data[D]; // Or an accessor function to avoid making it public
}
```

You would then add the `const` variation too.

It is more works but it is more flexible. For example, you can have proper validation of the dimension per function.

Alternatively, another solution is to have extra parameters to your algorithm for the transformation to apply.

```
template <typename Iterator, typename FA, typename FB>
void dummyFunction(Iterator begin, Iterator end, FA fa, FB fb)
{
  for (auto it = begin; it != end; it++)
  {
    cout << "Before: " << fa(*it) << "," << fb(*it) << "\t";
    fa(*it) += 1;
    fa(*it) -= 1;
    cout << "After: " << fa(*it) << "," << fb(*it) << "\n";
  }
}
```

This might seems a lot of work but then you are very flexible. So maybe, you can reconsider which code you want to modify.

It might be better to make such change now and have cleaner code in the future than to create an adaptor or add many functions to `GenericWidgetData` that are intended to be used only by the algorithms.

Comment: "Neverthless, the best solution would probably be to modify the 1000 functions so that instead of accessing directly members of LegacyWidgetData, then would call a free function."

I take it you've never worked in a code base in which certain parts are read-only ?

Comment: If your software company wrote the code and the code is not adequate anymore, then improve it. If you use a lot your library of 1000 functions, then making them easier to use would pay by itself in simplicity of writing new code and reduced maintenance. Unit testing is a good way to ensure you don't introduce new bugs in your code but given that your change are trivial, maybe you could make a copy of the code and change it. With **find and replace** you might be able to update the library in a day or 2.